# Azure Notification Hub device registration

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-notificationhub, visual-studio-app-center

Since AppCenter retiring at the end of this year, I have started migrating to Azure-Notification-Hub.
But the [documentation for notification-hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/) is not clear at all. Especially the documentation for Xamarin.Android. It does not match with their latest SDK.

In the latest (version 1.1.1) azure-notification-hub SDK for [Android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-android) (or [Xamarin.Android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Azure.NotificationHubs.Android/)) there's no need to implement `FirebaseMessagingService`. `NotificationHub.Start()` method registers the device in the Notification-Hub. A device registered with this way gets notifications without any problem.

```
NotificationHub.Start(Application, <HubName>, <ConnectionString>);
```

Addition tags to existing NotificationHub instance are also straightforward with the new SDK.

```
NotificationHub.AddTag("username:user123");
```

But in [Registration Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management#installations) official doc states that devices can register with the notification-hub either from client-side or from server-side. Is it necessary to use one of those methods if my app registered with the notification-hub using the `NotificationHub.Start()` method? Or do I missing something?

Also, when I was using the AppCenter, I have used the AppCenter-InstallId to target a specific device.
With that in mind is it possible to use the `NotificationHub.InstallationId`  to use as a tag (eg: `"handle:<devce's InstallationId>"`) to send device-specific notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to use one of those methods if my app registered with the notification-hub using the NotificationHub.Start() method?

When you invoke `NotificationHub.start(Application, ...)`, the Android SDK will listen for changes like added tags, new FirebaseMessagingService tokens, etc. Anytime it detects a change, it will invoke an `InstallationAdapter` to inform a backend of the new details.

The default `InstallationAdapter` will send an PUT request to the Azure Notification Hubs backend as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/create-overwrite-installation). This is what is created by `NotificationHub.start(Application, string, string)`;  for people who are not hosting their own backend, this is a sensible default.

If you have your own backend where you track devices, or you're just looking to keep your credentials server-side, you can swap out the `InstallationAdapter` to be a class that invokes your API. All you need to do is implement the [`InstallationAdapter` interface](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-android/blob/84e8d0bae65d8efd73f6c061c03d83a875ad6b05/notification-hubs-sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/messaging/notificationhubs/InstallationAdapter.java#L10) and initialize the SDK by calling [`NotificationHub.start(Application, InstallationAdapter)`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-android/blob/84e8d0bae65d8efd73f6c061c03d83a875ad6b05/notification-hubs-sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/messaging/notificationhubs/NotificationHub.java#L126).

If you use the `NotificationHub.start(...)` methods as indicated above, there is no further registration action required.

> With that in mind is it possible to use the NotificationHub.InstallationId to use as a tag (eg: "handle:<devce's InstallationId>") to send device-specific notifications?

Yes! [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management#installations) walks you through how to use the special tag format `$InstallationId:{YOUR_TAG_ID}` to target a specific device.

When you've used `NotificationHub.start()`, if you do not specify an `InstallationId`, it will generate one for you.

Comment: Thank you @MarStr! That helped to resolve my main concerns. As stated here, the expiration date of the `InstallationId` pushed ahead 90 days each time `NotificationHub.Start(...)` is called. In [this article] it says that like in appcenter, to disable receiving push notifications setting `NotificationHub.Enabled` to false would stop refreshing tokens until it expires. Does it mean the app will receive notifications for more 90 days? 
If I wanted to temporarily disable push, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Good question - if you call `NotificationHub.setEnabled(false)`, you should stop being informed of notifications immediately, and any updates to the device record will only be stored locally, i.e. the `InstallationAdapter` will not be invoked. Once you re-enable it, everything will begin again. Either way, you should keep calling `NotificationHub.start` so that changes to things like tags can be tracked locally.

Comment: I forgot to add links to my above comment, my mistake.
1. "As stated here" (article regarding the expiration date) - [Device expiry for Notification Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/push-notification-hub-telemetry-expiry-update/)
2. "In [this article] it says" (article regarding `NotificationHub.Enabled` - [Migrating off App Center Push](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/appcenter/migrating-off-app-center-push/)

Comment: @MatStr - My app is a Xamarin.Android app. Even if I set `NotificationHub.setEnabled(false)` (or in Xamarin `NotificationHub.Enabled = false` the app still received pushes. Like stated in [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/appcenter/migrating-off-app-center-push/): "**When disabled, push tokens are not refreshed but pushes are still received until the current token expires**"

Answer (score 0):

Question about setting the InstallationId and/or UserId.  If I'm using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Client, which makes more sense to do.

Should I set the InstallationId via the $InstallationId Tag (see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management#installations) or via implementing the InstallationEnrichmentAdapter and set it via a call to installation.InstallationId =  in the EnrichInstallation method?

Additionally, the `Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.Client.Installation` class provides a UserId property that can be updated too.

I'm also moving my push notifications from AppCenter to Azure Notification Hub and want to reuse my existing AppCenter `InstallId`.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: @TomK you have posted a question, so please ask this as a separate question. 
However a quick comment on your last part: you can't reuse your AppCenter `InstallId` on Notification Hub.

Answer (score 0):

i am able to add tags and userid as below(java)

```
NotificationHub.start(this.getApplication(), BuildConfig.hubName, BuildConfig.hubListenConnectionString);
NotificationHub.setInstallationId("123");
Set<String> tags = new HashSet<>();
tags.add("role_memeber");
NotificationHub.setUserId("123");
NotificationHub.addTags(tags);
```

sdk: [com.microsoft.azure:notification-hubs-android-sdk:1.1.6](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-android/blob/main/notification-hubs-sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/messaging/notificationhubs/NotificationHub.java)